# Migrating from mysql to PDO, Not connecting to mysql server

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

After a long time using `mysql` I finally decided to migrate everything to `PDO` as the prior is being depreciated.

I began by looking into some tutorials on using PDO, and right from the start I am having problems...

I am running:

> Apache (v2.2.22)
>   MySQL (v5.5.28)
>   PHP5

I am using the following block of code in PHP:

```
try{
    echo "PDO Connecting";
    $Connection = PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_database;charset=UTF-8", "username", "passwd");
    echo "Connected";
}catch(PDOException $ex){
    echo "Error!";
}
```

My problem is that I see the message `PDO Connecting`, and then nothing... No Connected message, nor error message... Any thoughts as to what the problem is and how to fix it?

Is PDO the best route? Or should I look into MySQLi instead?

**EDIT**

Results from var_dump(PDO::getAvailableDrivers());

> array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "mysql" [1]=> string(6) "sqlite" }

Results from Apache error.log

> PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function PDO() in /path/to/file.php on line 33

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the "new" keyword.

```
    $Connection = new PDO(......)
```

Make sure that you turn the error_reporting on to catch further errors.

Comment: Wow... thank you... Ill accept this in 4 minutes when I can... Cant believe I missed that... xD

Answer (score 2):

use `new` for `PDO class`

```
$Connection = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_database;charset=UTF-8", "username", "passwd");
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is PDO the best route? Or should I look into MySQLi instead?

Mysqli pretty much resembles mysql, so, it could be more familiar.
The only thing different is that connection resource should be always passed to any mysqli function, unlike mysql, where it's optional.

Comment: As I am familiar with MySQL, do you think MySQLi would be a better route then PDO, as opposed to relearning all of the functions?

Answer (score 0):

```
charset=UTF-8
```

[should be](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-odbc-configuration-connection-parameters.html):

```
charset=utf8
```

Yes, go with PDO (my opinion).

Also: turn on [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/book.errorfunc.php) so you get some feedback when you get an error, and learn how to report [PDO errors](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php).

Edit: also, see [how to handle PDO errors as exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php), as you seem to be expecting.

Comment: I have tried `UTF-8` as well as `utf8` both were suggested in the tutorial I followed, no change.

Comment: Turn on error reporting, so that you can see any errors; oh, and two answers above mine point out the obvious (that I missed!)